# Generate QR codes missing the corner

Tags: qr-code

I need to generate QR codes to add to a keychain. The thing is keychain has a rounded off missing corner: [image]

Is there any way to generate QR codes that can successfully be written and read without that corner. I'd prefer not to have to shrink it down to avoid that corner and leave a bunch of blank space.

Luckily I only need to encode 6-7 characters, I do however need to create *a lot* of different ones.

Is this doable without a custom QR reader?

Comment: You can probably just cut out that corner of your QR codes and let the error correction handle it.

Comment: @user2357112 That's sounds a bit...risky. Is there a way to calculate the odds of that working?